# How can I pass variable from ajax file to view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

My question is: I can render ajax request as I want, but I want to pass the @products variable in my ajax file(products.js.erb) to my js file called `index.js` , `category.html.erb` is where I send Ajax request from.

Categories controller index action corresponding views/category/index.html.erb the place where I send Ajax request to products controller list products action.

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @categories = Category.all
   end
end 

class ProductsController < ApplicationController

    def list_products 
      group_id = params[:group_id]

      @products = Product.where(GROUP: group_id)

      respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :file => "app/views/category/products.js.erb" } 
    end
   end
end
```

this is my products.js.erb content. It works, it render html content correctly, but I also want to pass or access as js variable or json my @product variable at index.js too (belongs to category controller index action view).

```
 <% href = "#"%>
 <% class_html = 'list-group-item'%>
 $('#product_list').empty();
 <% @products.each do |product| %>
    $('#product_list').append('<%=j("<a href=#{href} class=#{class_html}>#{product.ADI}</a>").html_safe %>');
<% end %>
```

I want to access `@products` variable in my js file too (`order.js`) 
order.html.erb

```
<%= link_to sgroup.ADI, products_path(group_id: "Z55"), class: 'list-group-item', remote: true %>
```

In short,  I want to use what I get via Ajax get request, in this case @products variable at my index.js file.

Comment: Can you try to clean up your question pls ? Show us a little bit more about your structure and what you want, it's too much muddlded to be able to help you.

Comment: Ok I will do my best

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

Comment: @ruby_newbie I have already tried  two solutions but it did not work for me